# What is 'vending' in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

After reading through some of the React Native docs I was left wondering where the term 'vend' comes from.  Can anyone elucidate the etymology of 'vend' or whether the word could benefit from a more expansive definition than the procedural one given in the docs ([this one is from the React Native iOS docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-ios.html)):

> Vending a view is simple:
>
> - Create the basic subclass.
> - Add the RCT_EXPORT_MODULE() marker macro.
> - Implement the -(UIView *)view method

Answer (score 0):

In this case, vend is synonymous with 'serve'. Try replacing each instance of 'vend'  with 'serve' and it should make sense to you.

> The key is to make the RCTMapManager a delegate for all the views it vends, and...

.

> You can see we're setting the manager as the delegate for every view that it vends, then...

.

> These subclasses are similar in function to view controllers, but are essentially singletons - only one instance of each is created by the bridge. They vend native views to the RCTUIManager, which...

Comment: I have a background in web development so 'serve' seems a little strange to me in this context.  Aren't we talking about the bridge between the OS and React Native?  For example, in a web context, I wouldn't say React's virtual DOM is serving views, although I guess that does make some sense.  Maybe 'vend' is a portmanteau referring to virtual rendering per se.

Comment: Exactly. I'm using serve as in a sort of servitude, where one thing delivers (or serves) something over the bridge to another.