# In the context of iOS development, what does vend mean?

Tags: ios, uikit

In WWDC's [Evolution of View Controllers](https://youtu.be/9_yNjb2K8oU?t=4m00s), around 04:00 the speaker says this:

"...or we could use this as the View Controller class that we vend to a Page View Controller with its data source methods."

Does vend mean link, or attach? But in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36143297/what-is-vending-in-react-native/36153650), someone says it means serve, but that might be specific to React? Also, in other [WWDC presentations](http://asciiwwdc.com/2012/sessions/223?q=vend), link makes more sense. What does vend mean and how was it derived?

Comment: Sounds like you could think of a vending machine that serves up something.  Just a guess.

Comment: It means "give" or "make available".

Comment: Why the down-votes? This seems like a reasonable question to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just means "provide to."

A page view controller displays an array of view controllers as it's pages. It gets those view controllers from it's data source.

You "vend" the array of view controllers to the page view controller, or offer them to the page view controller.

Comment: Right. No special jargon here. Just the dictionary meaning of 'vend'.

Comment: @Tommy, this usage of "vend"  has a CS "flavor" to it, I'd call it a semi-jargonish use of a regular English word.